# Criar linha no TSimpleGraph

Tags: grafo

Boa tarde.

Estou utilizando o TSimpleGraph para criar grafos no meu programa. Gostaria de criar uma linha horizontal através do código, escolhendo sua posição no form. [image: Linha]. Gostaria também que ela fosse pontilhada e preta. No programa que vem em anexo com o TSimpleGraph exite uma maneira de você criar diretamente no layout, porém eu queria através do código.

Agradecida.